# Seg fault while using MPI_Scatter

Tags: c++, mpi

I have problem with MPI_Scatter. Dont know hot to use it and my current program crashes with seg fault when I launch.

I guess that the problem in parameters of MPI_Scatter, particularly in calling it with right operator (& or * or void), but I've tried almost every combination and nothing actually helped.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

// k = 3, N = 12,  1,2,3, 4,5,6, 7,8,9, 10,11,12

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int N, size, myrank;
    int k;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::cin >> k;
    int *mass = new int[N];
    int *recv = new int[k];

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);

    if (myrank == 0) {
        std::cout << "get k and n \n";

        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            mass[i] = i;
            std::cout << i << " written\n";
        }
    }

    MPI_Scatter(mass, k, MPI_INT, recv, k, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int sum = 0;
    std::cout << "myrank" << myrank << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        std::cout << recv[i] << '\n';
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

When I launch this code, it prints this:

```
N = 12
k = 3
get k and n 
0 written
1 written
2 written
3 written
4 written
5 written
6 written
7 written
8 written
9 written
10 written
11 written
myrank0
0
1
2
myrank1
myrank3
myrank2
[1570583203.522390] [calc:32739:0]          mpool.c:38   UCX  WARN  object 0x7fe1f08b2f60 was not returned to mpool mm_recv_desc
[1570583203.523214] [calc:32740:0]          mpool.c:38   UCX  WARN  object 0x7f4643986f60 was not returned to mpool mm_recv_desc
[1570583203.524205] [calc:32741:0]          mpool.c:38   UCX  WARN  object 0x7f22535d4f60 was not returned to mpool mm_recv_desc
```

Comment: `int mass = new int[N];` your compiler let you do that, without, a least, a warning?

Comment: yep. I don't know how to do this in other way, actually...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with C/C++, but I found this implementation of dynamic arrays somewhere, and it works.

Comment: Ohh, I get it... There should be * before mass, of course

Comment: yeah, it should be a pointer, better yet, a smart pointer, as, you can see, you forget to delete them

Comment: @makaronistew you may find [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) easier to manage than dynamic arrays.

Comment: I fixed it, but there what it prints with 4 processes:
```12
3
get k and n 
0 written
1 written
2 written
3 written
4 written
5 written
6 written
7 written
8 written
9 written
10 written
11 written
myrank0
0
1
2
myrank1
myrank3
myrank2
[1570583203.522390] [calc:32739:0]          mpool.c:38   UCX  WARN  object 0x7fe1f08b2f60 was not returned to mpool mm_recv_desc
[1570583203.523214] [calc:32740:0]          mpool.c:38   UCX  WARN  object 0x7f4643986f60 was not returned to mpool mm_recv_desc
[1570583203.524205] [calc:32741:0]   ...      ```

Comment: yeah, vectors are more comfortable to use, but I don't know is there a special MPI's type for such a special classes. I mean, what should I pass when call MPI_scatter instead of MPI_INT when I use ```std::vector```?

Comment: done. (edited my question, added output)

Comment: modern implementations of std::vector` [have a `data` method](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data) you can call to get a pointer to the `vector`'s data buffer. Previously you could `&myvec[0];` which is technically undefined behaviour, but I've never seen a`vector` implementation where it doesn't work (and can't imagine why anyone would write one). In your case, `MPI_Scatter(mass.data(), ...);` should do the deed.

Comment: Oh, I see, but I should also pass MPI_Type parameter, when I call Scatter, which is MPI_INT in my case. So when I use vec.data() method, which type would this data buffer be (in terms of MPI's standard data types)? And I hope, this is the only problem with my code?

Comment: This is a place where good variable names (and a bit more familiarity with MPI on my part) would help debugging a lot. I'm not sure if `MPI_Scatter(mass, k` is correct. `mass` was sized with `N`, so if `N` < `k` could be a problem.

Comment: @makaronistew -- What exactly is the purpose of `N` in your code?  You don't really do anything with it, except to allocate `N` items.  You don't pass it to any routine, and in your API call, you're using `k`, not `N`.  I am not familiar with mpi, but that's what caught my eye.

Comment: I do not think `N` and `k` are set correctly on ranks != 0. you should also ensure `N >= k * size`.

Comment: `vector`'s a template, so its type is whatever you want it to be. std::vector<int> mass(N);`'s `mass.data()` would return an `int *`.

Comment: Also, once you have `N` and `k`, you don't need to refer to these variables again if you have a vector of `N` and `k` elements.  Use `vector::size()` if you want to get the number of items in the vector, as `size()` never fails.  If you use extraneous variables to denote the number of items in a vector, you're at risk of using "stale" variables that do not actually reflect the current number of entries in the vector.

Comment: But let me know if I'm wrong, I thought that second parameter of MPI_Scatter (which is k in my case) is the sendcount - the number of elements sent to each process (but not the total number of elements sent).

Comment: `sendcount` **is** the number of elements send to **each** process.

Comment: Well, yes, I want it to be just k.
For example, n = 12, k = 3. proc_count = 4. It should send 3 elements of an array to each process. So ```sendcount=3```

Comment: I found an interesting feature. when I write a constant instead of k (that is, just the number 3), then the behavior of the program is expected. But as soon as I change it to a variable, then everything breaks down.

Comment: see my comment 30 minutes ago and the answer i just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPI typically redirects `stdout` to rank 0, so `N` and `k` are not correctly set on the other ranks.

Here is a working version of your program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

// k = 3, N = 12,  1,2,3, 4,5,6, 7,8,9, 10,11,12

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int k, N, size, myrank;
    int *mass;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);


    if (myrank == 0) {
        std::cout << "get k and n \n";
        std::cin >> N;
        std::cin >> k;
        assert (N >= k*size);
        mass = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            mass[i] = i;
            std::cout << i << " written\n";
        }
    }
    MPI_Bcast(&k, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int *recv = new int[k];

    MPI_Scatter(mass, k, MPI_INT, recv, k, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int sum = 0;
    std::cout << "myrank" << myrank << '\n';
    for (int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
        std::cout << recv[i] << '\n';
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Now everything has become very-very clear

Comment: I hope I also someday can know programming as well as you and live and work in Japan. Thank you again!

Comment: all you needed here was an extra pair of eyes. Japan is great, and we can be singing "sweet home Alabama" all summer long :-)